# Does apt-offline update Linux or just packages?

Tags: updates, offline

I have a Linux build which is 100% quarantined from the internet. I've learned that Cube Server as well as apt-offline will help me install applications offline, which is great. But what's less clear is if **apt-offline** will also update the OS and all installed apps. I.e. I want to update a brand new Linux installation.

I just want to make sure I'm using the right tool for that, and the other questions I've found around here don't seem to explicitly say. Thanks! :)

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 -- apt-offline is an ubuntu package

Comment: @NotMyRealName -- If you have enough of the right packages it should be able to upgrade an installation, but keep in mind we are talking about thousands of packages.

Comment: I have never used apt-offline, but this looks pretty promising:  https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, that's a great article on **apt-offline** 's usage. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is just another set of packages in the Ubuntu archives. If you have all the appropriate packages in your media that you are installing from, then apt-offline should be able to install them just as well as any application your installing with it.